# Thor - inject into file at end

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, thor

I am working on a rails engine and I am trying to write a generator that will put this line

```
do_stuff (foo)
```

as the last statement in `config/routes.rb`, without breaking the file syntax.

Specifically, if my `config/routes.rb` looks like this currently

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    blah
    more blah
end
```

After running the generator I would like the `config/routes.rb` to look like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    blah
    more blah
    do_stuff (foo) # injected line
end
```

I looked at what [ActiveAdmin does](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/generators/active_admin/install/install_generator.rb), but am unable to create a blanket last line rule. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i did not test that out, but i think from what you linked to in the ActiveAdmin generator it might work like this:

```
inject_into_file "config/routes.rb", "  do_stuff(foo)\n", :before => /^end/
```

this should insert your code right before an `end` token that starts at the beginning of a line. this only works for properly formatted routes files though....

Comment: I thought of that. But I was wondering if Thor could be more intelligent. Problem with such before is that it will inject the line before the first `end` which could be a block.

Comment: thor would have to know about the code tree to do what you are thinking about. this is not a trivial thing, you can read about ruby AST and things like ripper, which is part of the STDLIB.

Comment: the regular expression that i used will not insert it to any `end`. it will look for the one that is not indented. in a properly indented/formatted file this should work like a charm.

Comment: Brilliant. I think I can live with that assumption. Thanks. I dont think I'd go the route of AST, seems too much for what I want to achieve.